# How do I slide li classes left on mouseenter and right on mouseleave?

Tags: jquery, slide, mouseleave, mouseenter

I'm trying to add a slide left on mouseenter and slide right on mouseleave to multiple li classes that are being used by an image swap script already with a hover function.

```
<script type>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumb ul li a').hover(
            function() {
                var currentBigImage = $('#gallery img').attr('src');
                var newBigImage = $(this).attr('src');
                var currentThumbSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
                switchImage(newBigImage, currentBigImage, currentThumbSrc);
            },
            function() {}
            );
            function switchImage(imageHref, currentBigImage, currentThumbSrc) {
                var theBigImage = $('#gallery img');
                if (imageHref != currentBigImage) {
                theBigImage.fadeOut(250, function(){
                    theBigImage.attr('src', imageHref).fadeIn(250);
                    var newImageDesc = $("#thumb ul li a img[src='"+currentThumbSrc+"']").attr('alt');
                    $('p#desc').empty().html(newImageDesc);
                });
            }
    }
});
</script
```

When I try using the script below in the same script as the one above, under `$('#thumb ul li a').hover(`, it breaks the existing hover function that swaps images and the li classes don't slide or do anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumb ul li a').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({left:'20px'}, 500)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({right:'20px'}, 500)
});
```

Should I run separate scripts, one to swap images and another to slide the links under `#thumb ul li a` that I have defined as li classes? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using hover for both sets of bindings, why don't you try using:

```
$('#thumb ul li a').bind("mouseenter", function() {});
```

and

```
$('#thumb ul li a').bind("mouseleave", function() {});
```

for one of your set of functions?

You could also try using namespacing in your bindings, such as:

```
.bind("mouseenter.name1", function() {})
.bind("mouseenter.name2", function() {})
.bind("mouseleave.name1", function() {})
.bind("mouseleave.name2", function() {})
```

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with this either, I'm guessing it has something to do with the script I'm already running.